# How to Run App in Background in Xamarin forms Cross platform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I have developed a xamarin cross platform application and it is working fine in both iOS and Android.

Now we need to add a new feature: Keep the app open in the background even when it's closed. There is an action (email sending) that should happen every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Background services (when app is in a background mode, not closed) is your solution, take a look:

iOS - Updating an Application in the Background: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/ios_backgrounding_techniques/updating_an_application_in_the_background/#background_fetch

Android - Creating Android Services:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/