# Xamarin long-running background task

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, background, mvvmcross

Long Running task in Xamarin, the app is in MVVM pattern using MVVMCross.
The goal is to make the app run in the background in both platforms (iOS and Android) even if the user kills the app.
I am wondering if there is any way to write code in the Core project.

Comment: https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48193832/how-to-run-app-in-background-in-xamarin-forms-cross-plotform

Comment: @Jason , I am currently looking at it, but I am not sure it will work with MVVMCross.

Comment: @Berjak I have a .NET class library that has the code to run in Background, the link you shared is the solution for the platform specific implementation.

Comment: @MahdiKhardani Shiny already supports MVVMCross (Shiny.Integrations.MvvmCross) and Reactive, Prism, etc... check the Shiny.Integrations.* namespace

Comment: @SushiHangover will do, thank you!

Comment: @Jason after few days of experimentation, Shiny works perfectly with Android, but not with iOS.
Due to the OS Restrictions, I had to implement platform-specific code for iOS enabling the Background Mode and adding the Background Fetch option and followed Xamarin's documentations for it but no luck.